# How to Control Concurrency to access the Row by Different processes at same time

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

My Oracle DB have one table called CONFIG

```
 CONFIG:
    | Name     | Value  |
    | -------- | ------ |
    | Modifier | A      |
```

My requirement is to write a procedure which access the the ow with name "Modifier" increment the value by one and update on table and return the value.

But problem was when two processed access the row at the same time then how to control concurrency.
Example:

Suppose there are two transactions T1 and T2. They are run in parallel.
Let's initially say Modifier was A

- T1 runs and updates the Modifier to B
- T2 also runs at the same time and updates the Modifier, it should be updated to C instead of B.

Comment: You can use locks and rely on relational integrity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an explicit cursor with the FOR UPDATE syntax  to acquire a lock on the table.

```
create or replace function update_modifier return varchar2 as
  cursor get_config is
    select * 
    from config
    where name = 'modifier'
    for update of value;
  r_config config%rowtype;
begin
  open get_config;
  fetch get_config into r_config;

  -- I'm not going to guess at your logic for "incrementing" a string
  r_config.value := 'something';

  update config
  set value = r_config.value
  where current of get_config;

  commit;

  close get_config;

  return r_config.value;

end update_modifier;
```

Notes

- the FOR UPDATE acquires a row level lock on the table when we open the cursor. The lock is maintained until we issue a commit (or rollback).
- Any other session calling this procedure will wait for this session to release the lock. If you would like the other session's call to return instead, use the NOWAIT option. Or use WAIT to specify a number of seconds to wait for the lock to come free before aborting.
- It's covered in the docs. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#i2066346)